# Delete rows of dataframe according to condition (comparing data in two columns)

Tags: dataframe, for-loop, if-statement, iteration, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe with trade flows (exports) between countries of origin and countries of destination (which are specified in two different columns of the df). I need to clean the data and **delete rows where the country of destination matches the country of destination**. I used the following code:

```
dfn = dfn[dfn["Destination"] != dfn["Origin"]]
```

However, I realized I actually need to **keep the lines where "World" is both in destination and origin** (i.e. total world exports towards the world). How can I delete all rows where destination == origin **except** for the rows where world == destination == origin?

I was thinking of interating through my ~2 million rows and delete only those where a certain conditionality applies. I tried something along those lines, but it doesn't really work. Could you please help me?

```
for index, row in dfn.iterrows():
         if row['Destination'] == row['Origin'] and row['Destination'] =! 'World':
            df.drop(index, inplace=True)
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple conditions using the '|' (or) operator and the .loc method

dfn = dfn.loc[(dfn['Destination'] != dfn['Origin']) | (dfn['Destination'] == 'World'), ]

Let me know how it works,
Matthieu